# Can't set UserDir to ~/Home/public_html in Multipass on MacOS host

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, multipass

I'm on MacOS host, running a Multipass instance which I'm using as a LAMP server.
Multipass maps ~/Home directory to the MacOS user directory and inside that directory I wanna have the public_html directory so I can develop from MacOS and the changes can be reflected in the Ubuntu LAMP.

Well, I've successfully enabled UserDir by running `sudo a2enmod userdir`, commenting out:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

from `/etc/apatche2/mods-enabled/php8.1.conf`

and replacing:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

with

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=ubuntu
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=ubuntu
```

in `/etc/apache2/envvars`

With all of this, I now have a `~/public_html` in which I can put html and php files and it works fine but if I edit `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` from `/home/*/public_html` to `/home/*/Home/public_html` it doesn't work! I'm getting the 403.

The permissions for the public_html and a file inside is as follows:

```
ubuntu@primary:~$ ls -la ~/Home/public_html/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   96 Jan 16 18:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1792 Jan 16 17:52 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu   17 Jan 16 18:19 test.php
```

What am I doing wrong? What's the way to achieve the desired result which I explained in the beginning?

Comment: When you say “it doesn’t work” do you mean that you’re receiving 500s? 404s? 403s? Fatal errors? Something else? Can I also confirm that on your MacOS host the full source directory is something like `/Users/kristijan/Home/public_html`?

Comment: I'm getting the 403. I've updated the post with the permissions info for the whole path.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu instance using AppArmor? If so, then you’ll need to add a rule to allow this different directory. AppArmor will prevent applications from accessing directories they shouldn’t have access to, which could be the reason for the 403.

Comment: I really have no idea why it doesn't work but I've realized that just symlinking whatever directory I want back into the ~/public_html like so: `ln -s ~/Home/public_html/ ~/public_html/public_html` works around the issue.

Comment: But yes, apparmor seems to be loaded:
`$ sudo aa-status`  
`apparmor module is loaded. \
33 profiles are loaded. \
33 profiles are in enforce mode.`

Answer (score 0):

Just symlinking whatever directory you want back into the ~/public_html like so: `ln -s ~/Home/public_html/ ~/public_html/public_html` fixes the issue.